# Finding the calculation that generates a NaN

Tags: python, debugging, numpy, scipy, nan

I have a moderately large piece (a few thousand lines) of Python/Numpy/Scipy code that is throwing up NaNs with certain inputs. I've looked for, and found, some of the usual suspects (`log(0)` and the like), but none of the obvious ones seem to be the culprits in this case.

Is there a relatively painless way (i.e., apart from putting exception handling code around each potential culprit), to find out where these NaNs are coming from?

Comment: You could monkey-patch `numpy.nan` to raise an exception...

Comment: What if NaN is generated in pure Python code? If `numpy.seterr` works, I'm confused - how would `numpy` be able to intercept what built-in Python does with NaN? If `numpy.seterr` doesn't work, then what are the recommended solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start with [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html).

There, an invalid operation is defined as "result is not an expressible number, typically indicates that a NaN was produced". By default, this seems to be set to "ignore".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.seterr` to set floating point error handling behaviour globally for all numpy routines. That should let you pinpoint where in the code they are arising from (or a least where numpy see them for the first time).